# Json do Facebook - Problemas com acentuação - Python

Tags: python, json, facebook, acentuação

Estou tentando importar o arquivo friends.json do Facebook, mas estou com problema na acentuação. O arquivo friends.json é algo como:

```
{
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "Marco Aur\u00c3\u00a9lio Ferreira",
      "timestamp": 1617453534
    },
    {
      "name": "Tha\u00c3\u00ads Everton D. Soares Papaleo",
      "timestamp": 1617420287
    }
          ]
 }
```

O código que eu estou usando é:

```
# encoding in UTF-8
import json

with open("friends.json", "r", encoding='UTF-8') as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    data = (data['friends'])
    for n in data:
        nome = n['name'] 
        print(nome)
```

Entretanto o retorno é o seguinte:

```
Marco AurÃ©lio Ferreira
ThaÃ­s Everton D. Soares Papaleo
```

Sinceramente eu já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo arrumar a acentuação. Alguém tem alguma luz?

Comment: tentou `latin-1`?

Comment: Sim. Tentei também a biblioteca codecs, função codecs.open, mas também não deu.

Comment: O fato de sair diferente do que espera aparenta ser um problema na hora do print (o lugar onde vc está lendo a string, seja console, IDE ou coisa do tipo não está em UTF-8), o que não quer dizer que no Py esteja errado. Se conseguir [edit] a postagem e fornecer um [mcve], ajudaria muito (edit: e colocar onde está usando a saída, se vai usar no console, que OS etc - fechamentos não tem intenção de ser definitivos e nem são punição, por isso sempre convidamos a editar os posts - não é pessoal, e não significa que não é bem vindo, muito pelo contrário).

Comment: Não era problema da IDE não. Mas a solução do Kaique deu certo. No mais a minha postagem era um um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável.

Answer (score -3):

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import json

with open("friends.json", "r", encoding='UTF-8') as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    data = (data['friends'])
    for n in data:
        nome = n['name'].encode('latin-1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
    print(nome)
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!!! Gastei metade do meu domingo nisso. rs...

Comment: Kaique Silva eu sei que o código funciona, eu testei, mas poderia por favor colocar uma explicação do porque ele funciona.

Comment: E explicar porque não fazer apenas `nome = n['name'].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: O JSON fornecido já é UTF-8 - esse é um dos motivos pelo qual é importante fechar postagens com falta de informações fundamentais, a pergunta sequer fala de como vai usar a saída. Entendo que o Kaique quer ajudar, mas na maioria dos cenários isso vai é piorar a situação (todas as postagens do site devem servir para um público amplo, e não como helpdesk individual). O código do autor da pergunta não dá o erro que ele menciona, quando você joga o output numa saida UTF-8. E obviamente que a sequência de encodes e decodes já deveria ser indicativo que não é uma "solução" muito natural.

Comment: Bacco, a maioria das pessoas entenderam a minha pergunta, tentaram me ajudar, mas você não. Talvez você esteja parcialmente certo e para um programa mais complexo existam saídas melhores, mas a solução do Kaique é simples e funciona, atendeu perfeitamente a minha necessidade. Se achava necessário eu falar a saída, você poderia ter pergunta, mas como ficou provado tal informação não era necessária. Pelos seus posts, parece que você nem testou o código que postei. Sei que sua intenção é boa. Mas se quer que a comunidade cresce, você precisa rever alguns conceitos.

Comment: Engano seu, @Otavio. Aqui não é um helpdesk. Resolver o problema do autor é quase um efeito colateral. Sobre testar, foi a primeira coisa que fiz antes de fechar o post (por isso pude com tranquilidade de dizer que não foi reproduzido o erro, pois numa saida UTF-8 a acentuação sai correta). Sobre rever conceitos, estou sempre aberto, mas tem dois que precisa de mais preparo pra me dizer; um, é sobre o objetivo do site, e outro, codificação de caracteres, a 2a tenho até mais expertise que a primeira (mas não estou competindo com ninguem). Inclusive, a solução aqui apresentada tem passos demais.

Comment: O próprio colega @AugustoVasques aponta algo muito mais simples, 2 passos que funcionam para latin-1 (que no seu caso talvez nem seja o correto, talvez seja win-1252, não sabemos onde vai usar - são parecidos, mas não iguais). Isto é facilmente verificável: https://ideone.com/yQS24V - porem só sabemos que é solução para o SEU caso, por ter funcionado onde usou, o que é quase coincidência. Sobre rever conceitos, talvez isto ajude: [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70)

Comment: De qualquer forma, não sou "dono" do site, o sistema é muito bem projetado. Se o moderador errar (e pessoas erram), simplesmente os usuários votam pela reabertura da postagem, e está resolvido. O que me sinto na obrigação é de ter deixado o comentário aqui tanto para que o  Kaique possa elaborar melhor a postagem se quiser, detalhando o que fez e por que ele entende que funcionaria, quanto para quem vier depois (que é o objetivo do site) use a informação da maneira mais completa possível. Ainda assim, a qualquer momento pode participar do [meta] e ter feedback de outros membros da comunidade.

Comment: Comecei a estudar Python a 2 semanas.Vi que neste site já havia várias perguntas similares com dúvidas sobre acentuação no python e testei todas antes de postar. O que indica a minha dúvida pode ser a de outros. Enfim Bacco. Acho que já investimos tempo demais com um problema que já está solucionado. Prometo tentar ser mais completo na próxima pergunta. E lamento o transtorno. rs...

Comment: **Objetivo do site: [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/).** Estou trancando os comentários, porque não é local de tirar duvidas sobre o que é o site. As dicas do Bacco sobre encoding, são pertinentes, inclusive no passado ele mesmo já me ajudou com isso, é algo que ele entende muito bem, o problema, recomendo a todos que sigam o código: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct e que entendam criticas construtivas. Se ainda sentir que precisa tirar duvidas sobre o funcionamento do site consulte o META https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ ou pergunta lá.

Comment: Olá @Otavio. Vale lembrar que nem sempre os fechamentos são definitivos, depende do autor melhorar a pergunta, lembrando sempre do [mcve], que é quase sempre a "regra chave" para que uma pergunta seja útil ao site e para que possa facilitar ser respondida. Todos são bem vindos a perguntar e responder, só lembrando de tentar entender alguns critérios mínimos para que o site não se torne apenas um helpdesk, Recomendamos a todos que leiam: [Guia de sobrevivência do SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/3635) para evitar fechamentos e aproveitar melhor o site.